# How to convert json to html table

Tags: javascript

Hi I need to convert the following json into a html table

```
{
  "condomini": [
    {
      "ricevute": [
        {
          "data": "31/10/2017",
          "numero": "1715759",
          "dettagli": "Contante",
          "descrizione": "Versamento giuseppe rossi rata ottobre ",
          "totale": "108,00",
          "righe": [
            {
              "importoPagato": "5,00",
              "importoCredito": "5,00",
              "importoResiduo": "0,00",
              "scala": "B",
              "piano": "2",
              "interno": "12",
              "descrizione": "Contributo per riparazione cancello A"
            },
            {
              "importoPagato": "103,00",
              "importoCredito": "103,00",
              "importoResiduo": "0,00",
              "scala": "B",
              "piano": "2",
              "interno": "12",
              "descrizione": "Rata ottobre - dicembre 2017"
            }
          ]
        }

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So far this is what I’ve managed to do, but i don’t know how to render the array “righe”, if you put the json code into http://json2table.com/ then you have an idea how the table should look like.

```
$.ajax({

 type: "json",
 url: "../km-client-controllers/km-ctrl-client-ricevute.php",

 success: function(result) {

  datas = JSON.parse(result);

  $('#nome_condominio').html(datas.condomini[0].condominio.nome);
  $('#indirizzo_condominio').html(datas.condomini[0].condominio.indirizzo);

  $.each(datas.condomini[0].ricevute, function(i, item) {


        var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(item.data),
            $('<td>').text(item.numero),
            $('<td>').text(item.descrizione),
            $('<td>').text(item.totale)
        ).appendTo('#records_table');


    });
```

Comment: do you have a fixed format of the json as above ? otherwise you will have to wrote a recursive json parser.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer no I don't think I have

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want your table to look, but to get the data inside the righe array you can do

```
 $.each(item.righe ....)
```

similar to how you getting the data from the ricevute array.

See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/zs0yowhk/21

Comment: Hi tahnks for your answer is it is working but I need to show the righe array into another table inside the righe column, if you copy and paste the json into  http://json2table.com/ you can see exactly what i mean, it's difficoult to explain without seeing how i need the table formatted :(

Comment: Make a new table inside your current table

Comment: Yes that is what i thought i should have done but not shure how to achieve it with javascript :(

Comment: var newtable = $("<table>");  and append that into a <td> in your current table

Comment: ok and where do I need to enter this code? Sorry i'm not very good with javascript :(